# Readable FoldRight via FoldLeft in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-dependencies

In [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), the author asks to express FoldRight via FoldLeft. And then the author offers the following [implementation](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answerkey/datastructures/13.answer.scala):

```
  def foldRightViaFoldLeftAuthor[A, B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    foldLeft(l, (b: B) => b)((g, a) => b => g(f(a, b)))(z)
  }
```

There have been a couple of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136794/foldleft-using-foldright-in-scala) asking to explain the author's solution. And probably a lot of people are still struggling to understand it.

While I was thinking about the task I came up with a different implementation that seems much more readable and easier to grasp at least for me

```
  def foldRightViaFoldLeftMy[A, B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    foldLeft(l, z)(((g: (A, B) => B) => (b: B, a: A) => g(a, b)) (f))
  }
```

So I basically prepare a function that converts `f(a,b)` to `f(b,a)` and now I'm able to call `foldLeft` that is tail-recursive.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any reason to implement it in the way the author did?
2. Are there any drawbacks in my implementation in comparison to the author's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written an implementation that has the same signature as `foldRight`, but it doesn't have the right semantics when the combination operation isn't commutative. To take one example, a right fold with the empty list as zero and cons as the combination operation should be identity:

```
scala> val input = List(1, 2, 3)
input: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val f: (Int, List[Int]) => List[Int] = _ :: _
f: (Int, List[Int]) => List[Int] = $$Lambda$1912/991363637@5e9bf744

scala> foldRightViaFoldLeftAuthor(input, List.empty[Int])(f)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

But your implementation reverses the list:

```
scala> foldRightViaFoldLeftMy(input, List.empty[Int])(f)
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

This is because you're still folding from left to right, even though you've switched the order of the combination function's arguments. I find the diagrams on [the Wikipedia page about `fold`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) useful for visualizing the difference. In your implementation the applications happen like this:

```
scala> f(3, f(2, f(1, Nil)))
res2: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

While in the book's implementation you have something like this:

```
((b3: List[Int]) =>
  ((b2: List[Int]) =>
    ((b1: List[Int]) => identity(f(1, b1)))(f(2, b2)))(f(3, b3)
  )
)(Nil)
```

Which boils down to:

```
scala> f(1, f(2, f(3, Nil)))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

So the answer to both of your questions is "yes", there is an important difference between your implementation and the book's.